# Masonry layout with bootstraps panel

Tags: jquery, html, css, masonry

Anyone here good with MasonryJs with bootstrap?

I'm having this issue : 
[image]

This is what I got so far

```
<div class="row" id="grid">
<div class="col-md-6 item">
<div class="panel panel-default>
.....
</div>
</div>
</div>

$("#grid").masonry({
 itemSelector: '.item',
 columnWidth: '.item'
});
```

Maybe someone can enlighten me why this is occuring? Thank

---

So I moved the grid class to grid id the this the result I got. Turns out that all the the panels are stack up as one.

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot indicates that Masonry isn't being initiated at all. Have you definitely included both jQuery and Masonry libraries in `script` tags and before the jQuery code you've posted executes? It would be helpful if you would let us know if the browser console is showing any errors.

Comment: @amdouglas I fix the row and added "grid" as an Id and I got the result about I edited my question. Turns out the panels are pilled up as one.

Comment: Just a guess: try adding this to your CSS: `#grid { position: relative }`

Comment: @amdouglas Hmmmp, nothing's change.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could share what you're working on somehow. Can you put what you have into a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/?html,css,js,output) or share a link to your project if you're not working locally? Otherwise we're just going to end up playing *20 Questions*.

Comment: Well I've update the [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/fodotuzeda/edit?js,output) and its working, but not on my local script -_-. sucks

Comment: So, basically, you're not using jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Masonry init code you're using, from the question:

```
$("#grid").masonry({
 itemSelector: '.item',
 columnWidth: '.item'
});
```

This is the init snippet for using Masonry with jQuery.

You do not appear to be using jQuery, so you need to use the vanilla JavaScript init for Masonry:

```
var elem = document.querySelector("#grid");
var masonry = new Masonry(elem, {
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-item'
});
```